# Laravel auto auth?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I need to secure my backend section.

Right now i have i like this:

```
Route::get('/backend',['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
Route::get('/backend/users',['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'HomeController@show']);
Route::get('/backend/users/create',['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'HomeController@create']);
Route::get('/backend/users/edit/{id}',['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'HomeController@edit']);
```

do i need to write the middleware=> auth to everyline and everysite i have in my backend?

Is it somehow possible to define that everything that has 'backend/' should be checked if auth or not?

Comment: You just need to use `Route::group()` instead [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Route Group](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-groups) to define middleware and a prefix (among other things). So it could be:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'backend', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/users', 'HomeController@show');
    Route::get('/users/create', 'HomeController@create');
    Route::get('/users/edit/{id}', 'HomeController@edit');
)};
```

Comment: hmm i am trying it but its not working. It says notfoundhttexception. Where is my mistake? (laravel 5.2 btw)
Route::group(['prefix' => 'backend', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
  Route::get('/backend', 'HomeController@index');
});

Comment: if you add the `'prefix' => 'backend'` part, remove "backend" from your individual routes (see my example above).